# Find work done by force along unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Find the work done by the force $e^y{\bf i}+xe^y {\bf j}$ along the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ traversed once counterclockwise from (1, 0)(1,0) back to (1, 0)(1,0).

I got this down to the integral from 0 to 2pi of e^sint(cos^2(t) - sint)dt but this seems uncomputable. Is there another way to do this with another theorem?

Comment: Did you try greens theorem?

Comment: no, isn't green's theorem utilized for integrals over the boundary closed by the unit circle? Sorry, I am just a little bit new to this

Comment: You have not written down the coordinates correctly. Please check.  It says "(1, 0)(1,0) back to (1, 0)(1,0)".

Comment: Green's theorem equates the line integral of a vector field over closed simple curve (or the work done by the force) with a double integral over the region that the curve encloses.

Comment: Btw your vector field is conservative. Its potential function is $xe^y$. So all this is unnecessary.

Comment: so is it just 0 since it's conservative and goes back to the same point?